# javascript Latitude Longitude to xyz position on earth (threejs)

Tags: javascript, geolocation, three.js

i´m playing arround with three.js

i want to render objects on specific geocoordinates on a bigger sphere, i´m pretty near to the solution, but i dont get the correct xyz position from lat lon

i have set up a test case on jsfiddle, there are two coordinates

```
latlons = [[40.7142700,-74.0059700], [52.5243700,13.4105300]];
```

its New York and Berlin

and this is my function to calc xyz from lat lon and radius

```
function calcPosFromLatLonRad(lat,lon,radius){

// Attempt1
var cosLat = Math.cos(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
var sinLat = Math.sin(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
var cosLon = Math.cos(lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
var sinLon = Math.sin(lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
var rad = radius;
y = rad * cosLat * sinLon;
x = rad * cosLat * cosLon;
z = rad * sinLat;

// Attempt2
// x = radius *  Math.sin(lat) * Math.cos(lon)
// y = radius *  Math.sin(lat) * Math.sin(lon)
// z = radius * Math.cos(lat)


// Attempt3
// latitude = lat * Math.PI/180
// longitude = lon * Math.PI/180
// x =  -radius * Math.cos(latitude) * Math.cos(longitude)
// y =  radius * Math.sin(latitude) 
// z =  radius * Math.cos(latitude) * Math.sin(longitude)


// Attempt4
// var phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180);
// var theta = (lng+180)*(Math.PI/180);
// x = ((rad) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
// z = ((rad) * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta));
// y = ((rad) * Math.cos(phi));



   console.log([x,y,z]);
   return [x,y,z];
}
```

but all attempts return different xy, and they are all not correct ( z is always correct).

could someone pleas guide me to the right way ? 
i have no idea what could be wrong

heres the fiddle to play with

[UPDATE: working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvtm639m/38/)

Comment: hmn why am i the only guy looking at this ?

Comment: you're ahead of your time :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

unfortunatly i can´t further explain, but after playing around this one works like a charme :)

```
function calcPosFromLatLonRad(lat,lon,radius){
  
    var phi   = (90-lat)*(Math.PI/180);
    var theta = (lon+180)*(Math.PI/180);

    x = -(radius * Math.sin(phi)*Math.cos(theta));
    z = (radius * Math.sin(phi)*Math.sin(theta));
    y = (radius * Math.cos(phi));
  
    return [x,y,z];

}
```

yeah thats pretty cool isnt it ?
And i´m still interested into some shorter equation

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvtm639m/38/)

Comment: Do you still have a working version of this somewhere? Checked the fiddle but it looks like three.js isn't loaded. I want to do the same thing.

Comment: check the link i added to this answer, it is working here!

Comment: Formula without radius please? Thank you.

Comment: @hamzox just remove the radius

Answer (score 6):

This function works for me:

```
function calcPosFromLatLonRad(radius, lat, lon) {

  var spherical = new THREE.Spherical(
    radius,
    THREE.Math.degToRad(90 - lon),
    THREE.Math.degToRad(lat)
  );

  var vector = new THREE.Vector3();
  vector.setFromSpherical(spherical);

  console.log(vector.x, vector.y, vector.z);
  return vector;
}

calcPosFromLatLonRad(0.5, -74.00597, 40.71427);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old thread but in case some are interested made that updated demo based on your previous demo running on current three js version:

https://3yftls.csb.app/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34432556)